# Is it possible to simulate or bypass pressure sensor on android device and feed custom data to application?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to simulate barometer sensor of an Andorid device so that i can feed my application custom data and check with out moving to different pressure zone.

Comment: the only simulator i know is here: https://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Comment: Hello opiatefuchs, I tried this simulator on real device i am able to record data but not to play it back to my device.